# Jenkins "Invalid Login Information"

Tags: authentication, ssh, jenkins

I have Jenkins setup to use Unix user/group database security but I cannot login with any users I create other than the one that's running the Jenkins service. Logging in on the server via ssh or su works but when I try to use the Jenkins interface it gives an "Invalid Login Information" message.

From what I've read I need to either run jenkins as root, or give the user that's launching Jenkins access to my shadow file. Neither or these are viable options for me. Are there any other workarounds?

After some more trials I've discovered that giving the user that launched Jenkins read access to the shadow file is not enough. I need to set read permissions for all users for the shadow file in order to be able to login with the other accounts. Further, I tried adding each user in passwd to the shadow group and that didn't work either so I'm not sure who Jenkins is trying to access the shadow file as when I try to login.

Jenkins log:

```
4-Dec-2012 11:05:28 AM hudson.security.AuthenticationProcessingFilter2 onUnsuccessfulAuthentication
INFO: Login attempt failed
org.acegisecurity.BadCredentialsException: pam_authenticate failed : Authentication failure; nested exception is org.jvnet.libpam.PAMException: pam_authenticate failed : Authentication failure
        at hudson.security.PAMSecurityRealm.authenticate(PAMSecurityRealm.java:78)
        at hudson.security.AbstractPasswordBasedSecurityRealm$Authenticator.retrieveUser(AbstractPasswordBasedSecurityRealm.java:137)
        at org.acegisecurity.providers.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:119)
        at org.acegisecurity.providers.ProviderManager.doAuthentication(ProviderManager.java:195)
        at org.acegisecurity.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:45)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:71)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:252)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilter(BasicProcessingFilter.java:173)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at jenkins.security.ApiTokenFilter.doFilter(ApiTokenFilter.java:63)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
        at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:66)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
        at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
        at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
        at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:50)
        at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
        at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
        at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
        at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
        at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
        at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:331)
        at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.processRequest(RequestHandlerThread.java:215)
        at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.run(RequestHandlerThread.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: org.jvnet.libpam.PAMException: pam_authenticate failed : Authentication failure
        at org.jvnet.libpam.PAM.check(PAM.java:106)
        at org.jvnet.libpam.PAM.authenticate(PAM.java:124)
        at hudson.security.PAMSecurityRealm.authenticate(PAMSecurityRealm.java:73)
        ... 34 more
```

Comment: Hitting the same issue trying to run jenkins with runit. Hadn't tried making `/etc/shadow` world readable.

Comment: adding the 'jenkins' user to shadow group worked for me

Answer (score 3):

According to [Hudson fails to use unix user/group to do authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666305/hudson-fails-to-use-unix-user-group-to-do-authentication), you have to do 2 things

- make sure that the user running jenkins has read access to /etc/shadow
- the service name must not be random in some cases. Platform specific.

2 ideas:

- use the Test button to validate the read access
- try changing your service name to 'ssh' or 'sshd' depending on your platform

You might want to edit https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PAM+Authentication+Plugin with your findings!

Comment: @Gallal At least make it 644 - 777 means that everyone can change everyone's password.